# JQuery/PHP to do simple division to readonly form field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok I have looked all over the web and I must be searching incorrectly because I know there is a way to do this.

Here is what I need to do. I have an input text field for the user to put in some number once they put that number in I want it to be divided by 1000 and the result I want to populate into a readonly text field right next to it.

The tricky part for me is I need to do this without a submit button or page refresh. Also the information that the user input needs to be available to be put into the database once they have completed the steps.

I know this is probably something that is very simple and I'm over-looking something. The website is built on WAX framework (not that it makes a difference).

here are the two inputs:

```
<div class="investment">
<dl class="investment_amount">
<dt>
<label for = "Investment Amount">Investment Amount</label>
</dt>
<dt>
<input type="text" class="invest" placeholder="Enter Investment Amount" name="investment_amount" value=""/>
</dt>
</dl>
<dl class="num_notes">
<dt>
<label for="Number of Notes">Number of Notes</label>
</dt>
<dt>
<input type="hidden" class="notes" placeholder="Number of Notes" name="number_of_notes" value="" />
<input type="text" id="note" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Notes" name="number_of_notes" value="" />
</dt>
</dl>

</div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, you need to use javascript. Check out using `blur` events on the text field

Comment: I tried using blur but it didn't work. I set up the investment_amount as a variable and divided it by 1000 but when I click outside the textbox nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/fgubc/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simple perform calculation by **onblur** event of Javascript as

first I am keeping an ID for your input field

```
<input type="text" class="invest" placeholder="Enter Investment Amount" name="investment_amount" value="" onblur="calculate()" id="txtamount"/>
```

I am changing your hidden field into readonly field, cause i don't know why you put hidden??? and adding an ID attribute for result field as well

```
<input type="text" class="notes" placeholder="Number of Notes" name="number_of_notes" value="" id="result" readonly/>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function calculate()
     {
          document.getElementbyId('result').value = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('txtamount').value) / 1000;
     }
</script>
```

**Note**

one more thing Kemmieg that never save a value into database which is calculated on Client machine like the one we are doing above because someone can easily change **divide by 1000** to **divide by 100** and if does then that value would be stored into Database. So, it would be better to show client the calculated value into a field but if you want to save calculated field value then calculate on server and then save the server calculated value into database not the javascript result value.